# bootstrap toggle navigaion causes line under logo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please i need help in removing the gray line under my logo "HeraldHome" after i toggle the nav in the image below. i have tried everything i can but it still remains the same;am using bootstrap, and here is my code for the nav:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
             <button style="background-color:white;border:1px yellowgreen;" type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="" style="font-size:39px;color:white;font-family:Grenadier NF;font-style:italic;padding-left:20px;">Herald<span style="font-size:34px;font-style:italic;">home</span></a>
    </div><!--navbar-header-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="ctive"><a href="" style="color:white;"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><br>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="" style="color:white;"><i class="fa fa-delicious"></i><br>About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="" style="color:white;"><i class="fa fa-glass"></i><br>Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="" style="color:white;"><i class="fa fa-calendar-minus-o"></i><br>Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="" style="color:white;"><i class="fa fa-    envelope"></i><br>Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div><!--navbar-collapse-->
    </div><!--container-->
<nav><!--navbar-->
```

[image: the image]

Comment: Your output comes this way: http://output.jsbin.com/zomotoveme. How can we help you? Please tell. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar You need bootstrap...

Comment: @Bern Still, with bootstrap: http://output.jsbin.com/zomotoveme, what can we do?

Comment: this are the contents of my stylesheet:                                                       ul li i
{
 padding-left: 13px;
 color: white;
}
.navbar-default
{
 background-color:yellowgreen;
}
ul
{
 color: white;
}
.ctive
{
 background-color: none;
 border-bottom: 3px solid white;
}
.navbar-header a:hover
{
 text-decoration: none;
}                                                                                                                                               i also used font awesome

Comment: @DavidNode How about you format your css and put it in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for a:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
     border-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```

DO NOT alter your bootstrap.css. Use a stylesheet to overwrite your bootstrap css by re-addressing the same class and resetting the border with:

```
border-color:transparent;
```

Comment: That's a guess. Please don't feed these kind of answers. `:)`

Comment: i already tried that but it did not work

Comment: Without the css it is impossible to know where his problem is, but following your link and bootstrap makes it easier to find. The original concept still applies. A guess? Sure, but a very educated guess. I found the issue and it was exactly what I thought it'd be

Comment: If your bootstrap class is still overwriting your override, add !important to your css reset or use CSS specificity. But it works for me

Comment: thanks a lot! it worked :)

Comment: of course lol glad my guess helped lol